# Simple in-page Javascript editor library

Tags: library, javascript

I'm looking for a Javascript library to be able to edit the contents of the page on-demand, within the browser itself. This will essentially take the place of a heavy CMS on my site. Here's what I have found so far:

- [Create.js](http://createjs.org/)
- [Runty](http://runtyapp.org/)
- CloudCannon (a commercial service)

There are many in-page editors like Aloha, Hallo, or TinyMCE, but I'm looking for a library that will help with sending changes back up to the server as well. Create.js is exactly what I'm looking for in terms of functionality, but it's huge in terms of dependencies (Backbone, jQuery UI, VIE). Are there any other libraries like this that are smaller/simpler that I'm missing?

Comment: You might want to ask at the new Code Recommendations on Area51 - "Proposed Q&A site for programmers seeking the best library for specific tasks" area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66606/code-recommendations

Comment: Thanks, I'll post this there as well.

Comment: In general, you should never cross-post (lest you feel the wrath of the moderator). Maybe best to delete this & repost (after upvoting my comments, of course ;-)